# How to get Jackson ObjectMapper to work with xjc generated classes containing Jakarta annotations?

Tags: java, xml, spring, jackson, jaxb

Here's my case,

I've generated some source files from some XSD & WSDL files. The generated sources have classes & attributes annotated with Jakarta annotations. There are 3 layers in my application,

1. controller layer - Spring MVC controllers. They take in one of the XJC-generated class objects as a request body and give out another one as a response body
2. client layer - A layer that creates a WebServiceTemplate with a Jaxb2Marshaller and forwards the request as a SOAP request to another URL
3. XML Element classes layer - XML type equivalent classes generated using xjc

The issue I'm facing is with parsing the attributes of classes of the type JAXBElement. Below is an example class,

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "filter",
    "initialTerminationTime",
    "subscriptionPolicy",
    "any"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "CreatePullPointSubscription")
public class CreatePullPointSubscription {
    @XmlElement(name = "Filter")
    protected FilterType filter;

    @XmlElementRef(name = "InitialTerminationTime", namespace = "http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> initialTerminationTime;

    ...
}
```

By default, considering these classes as POJOs, the generated schema shows that the ObjectMapper is expecting a JSON body reflecting the definition of JAXElement and not the type of the actual attribute. I don't want the user to send the additional attributes of the JAXBElement.

MyWebMvcConfigurer:

```java
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        SimpleModule serializerModule = new SimpleModule();
        serializerModule.addSerializer(JAXBElement.class, new JAXBJsonSerializer());
        serializerModule.addDeserializer(Object.class, new JAXBJsonDeserializer<>(Object.class));

        for (HttpMessageConverter o : converters) {
            if (o instanceof AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                ObjectMapper om = ((AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter)o).getObjectMapper();
                om.addMixIn(JAXBElement.class, JAXBElementMixin.class);

                // This line tells swagger to show what I expect
                ModelConverters.getInstance().addConverter(new ModelResolver(om));
                om.registerModule(serializerModule);
            }
        }

        WebMvcConfigurer.super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
```

The ModelResolver seems to just change the open API schema and not the actual deserialization. For this, I implemented a custom serializer and a deserializer as you can see in the above piece of code.

JAXBJsonDeserializer

```java
package com.ibi.onvif.web;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdScalarDeserializer;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class JAXBJsonDeserializer<T> extends StdDeserializer<T> {
    protected JAXBJsonDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    protected JAXBJsonDeserializer(JavaType valueType) {
        super(valueType);
    }

    protected JAXBJsonDeserializer(StdDeserializer<?> src) {
        super(src);
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        try {
            // Get the root element's class
            Class<?> rootType = ctxt.getContextualType().getRawClass();

            // Check if the root element is part of a JAXB-generated package
            if (isJAXBGenerated(rootType)) {
                Object objectFactory = getObjectFactory(rootType);

                // Deserialize the JSON into a JsonNode
                JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);

                // Identify the appropriate factory method by annotations or return type
                Method factoryMethod = findFactoryMethod(objectFactory, rootType, null);

                // Use the factory method to generate the object
                T rootObject = (T) factoryMethod.invoke(objectFactory);

                // Recursively process attributes
                processAttributes(objectFactory, rootObject, node, ctxt);

                return rootObject;
            } else {
                // If not a JAXB-generated class, use the default deserialization
                return ctxt.readValue(p, (Class<T>) rootType);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("JAXB deserialization error", e);
        }
    }

    private boolean isJAXBGenerated(Class<?> type) {
        // Implement logic to check if the class is part of a JAXB-generated package
        // For example, you can check package names or annotations.
        // Replace the following line with your actual logic.
        return type.getPackage().getName().startsWith("org.onvif");
    }

    private Object getObjectFactory(Class<?> type) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        String objectFactoryClassName = type.getPackage().getName() + ".ObjectFactory";
        Class<?> objectFactoryClass = Class.forName(objectFactoryClassName);
        return objectFactoryClass.newInstance();
    }

    private Method findFactoryMethod(Object objectFactory, Class<?> rootType, String attr) throws NoSuchMethodException, NoSuchFieldException {
        // If attr is null, the caller is asking for rootType factory method
        Method[] methods = objectFactory.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        if (attr == null) {
            for (Method method : methods) {
                if (method.getName().equals(String.format("create%s", rootType.getName()))) {
                    return method;
                }
            }
            throw new NoSuchMethodException("Factory method not found for class: " + rootType);
        }

        assert rootType.getField(attr).getType() == JAXBElement.class;

        for (Field field : rootType.getFields()) {
            if (field.getName().equals(attr)) {
                XmlElement annotation = field.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class);
                return objectFactory.getClass().getMethod(String.format("create%s%s", rootType.getName(), annotation.name()));
            }
        }
        
        throw new NoSuchMethodException("Factory method not found for class: " + rootType + " and attr: " + attr);
    }

    private void processAttributes(Object objectFactory, Object parentObject, JsonNode node, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, IOException, JAXBException, NoSuchMethodException, NoSuchFieldException {
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = node.fields(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = it.next();
            String fieldName = field.getKey();
            JsonNode fieldValue = field.getValue();

            // Find the corresponding object factory field value generator
            Method setterMethod = findSetterMethod(parentObject.getClass(), fieldName);

            // Get the attribute value
            Object attributeValue;
            Class<?> parameterType = setterMethod.getParameterTypes()[0];
            if (parameterType == JAXBElement.class) {
                // if it is a JAXBElement-type field, call ObjectFactory to get factory method
                Method fieldFactoryMethod = findFactoryMethod(objectFactory, parentObject.getClass(), fieldName);

                // get attribute value from the object factory attribute factory
                attributeValue = fieldFactoryMethod.invoke(objectFactory, ctxt.readTreeAsValue(fieldValue, fieldFactoryMethod.getParameterTypes()[0]));
            }   else    {
                attributeValue = ctxt.readTreeAsValue(fieldValue, parameterType);
            }

            // Invoke the setter method to set the attribute value
            setterMethod.invoke(parentObject, attributeValue);
        }
    }

    private Method findSetterMethod(Class<?> parentClass, String fieldName) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        return parentClass.getMethod(String.format("set%s", fieldName));
    }
}
```

JAXBJsonSerializer

```java
package com.ibi.onvif.web;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

import java.io.IOException;

public class JAXBJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        Object objectValue = ((JAXBElement<?>)value).getValue();
        gen.writeObject(objectValue);
    }
}
```

ObjectMapper never seems to use my deserializer. The exception it throws is as below

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of 
`jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBElement` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): 
no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('PT600S')
```

How do I get ObjectMapper to work?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried configuring the deserializer using an annotation on the classes containing the `JAXBElements`? Adding `@JsonDeserialize(using = JAXBJsonDeserializer.class)` to the generated classes - see [Jackson Deserialization](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization#on-class)? Probably not a long term solution, but might be something you could try instead of registering it on the `ObjectMapper` directly. Might be nothing to do with how you're registering it, but may be worth a shot if you're out of ideas!

Comment: I solved this. Posted the answer. The problem with annotating each generated class is I've got way too many of them, which is just too exhaustive

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a custom deserializer for the JAXBElement. The JsonParser class lets us access the parent element properties through which I can identify which class field the current JSON field is being deserialized for, and so extract annotations like `XmlElementRef` & `XmlElement`.

Please find the code below for the same.

JAXBElementDeserializer.java:

```java
public class JAXBElementDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<JAXBElement<?>>{
    public JAXBElementDeserializer() {
        super(JAXBElement.class);
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBElement<?> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        try {
            // Get the root element's class
            Class<?> rootType = p.getParsingContext().getCurrentValue().getClass();

            // Check if the root element is part of a JAXB-generated package
            if (isJAXBGenerated(rootType)) {
                Object objectFactory = getObjectFactory(rootType);

                // Deserialize the JSON into a JsonNode
                JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);

                // Identify the appropriate factory method by annotations or return type
                Method factoryMethod = findFactoryMethod(objectFactory, rootType, p.getCurrentName());

                //Get the parameter type
                Class<?> type = factoryMethod.getParameters()[0].getType();

                // Use the factory method to generate the object
                return  (JAXBElement<?>) factoryMethod.invoke(objectFactory, ctxt.readTreeAsValue(node, type));
            } else {
                // If not a JAXB-generated class, use the default deserialization
                throw new IOException();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException("JAXB deserialization error", e);
        }
    }

    private boolean isJAXBGenerated(Class<?> type) {
        // Implement logic to check if the class is part of a JAXB-generated package
        // For example, you can check package names or annotations.
        // Replace the following line with your actual logic.
        return type.getPackage().getName().startsWith("org.onvif");
    }

    private Object getObjectFactory(Class<?> type) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        String objectFactoryClassName = type.getPackage().getName() + ".ObjectFactory";
        Class<?> objectFactoryClass = Class.forName(objectFactoryClassName);
        return objectFactoryClass.newInstance();
    }

    private Method findFactoryMethod(Object objectFactory, Class<?> rootType, String attr) throws NoSuchMethodException, NoSuchFieldException {
        String annotatedName;
        assert rootType.getField(attr).getType() == JAXBElement.class;

        for (Field field : rootType.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.getName().equals(attr)) {
                XmlElement annotation = field.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class);
                if (annotation != null) {
                    annotatedName = annotation.name();
                }   else {
                    XmlElementRef ref_annotation = field.getAnnotation(XmlElementRef.class);
                    annotatedName = ref_annotation.name();
                }

                // Don't know the type, simple search the method by its name
                for (Method method : objectFactory.getClass().getMethods()) {
                    if (method.getName().equals(String.format("create%s%s", rootType.getSimpleName(), annotatedName))) {
                        return method;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        throw new NoSuchMethodException("Factory method not found for class: " + rootType + " and attr: " + attr);
    }
}
```

JAXBElementSerializer:

```java
public class JAXBElementSerializer extends JsonSerializer<JAXBElement> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(JAXBElement value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        Object objectValue = value.getValue();
        gen.writeObject(objectValue);
    }
}
```

WebMvcConfigurer.java:

```java
public class OnvifWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    // Mixins
    public static interface JAXBElementMixin {
        @JsonValue
        Object getValue();
    }

    public static interface DurationMixin {
        @JsonValue
        String toString();
    }

    final private Class<?>[][] MIXIN_CLASSES = {
            {JAXBElement.class, JAXBElementMixin.class},
            {Duration.class, DurationMixin.class},
    };
    
    private final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();

    private void setupModule() {
        module.addSerializer(JAXBElement.class, new JAXBElementSerializer());
        module.addSerializer(Duration.class, new DurationSerializer());
        module.addDeserializer(JAXBElement.class, new JAXBElementDeserializer());
        module.addDeserializer(Duration.class, new DurationDeserializer());
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new OnvifCredentialsExtractionInterceptor());
    }

    private void configureMixins(ObjectMapper om) {
        for (Class<?>[] pair : MIXIN_CLASSES) {
            om.addMixIn(pair[0], pair[1]);
            SpringDocUtils.getConfig().replaceWithClass(pair[0], pair[1]);
        }
    }

    private void configureMessageConverter(HttpMessageConverter<?> httpMessageConverter) {
        if (!(httpMessageConverter instanceof AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter)) {
            return;
        }
        ObjectMapper om = ((AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter) httpMessageConverter).getObjectMapper();
        configureMixins(om);
        ModelConverters.getInstance().addConverter(new ModelResolver(om));
        om.registerModule(module);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        setupModule();

        for (HttpMessageConverter<?> o : converters) {
            configureMessageConverter(o);
        }

        WebMvcConfigurer.super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!